# Error using FixedIncomeExpectedValue sample

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-computing-for-finance

I am working with Aqua sample (`qiskit-aqua/test/finance/test_readme_sample.py` ) that uses the `FixedIncomeExpectedValue` and the `AmplitudeEstimation`.

It is `qiskit 0.18`

This sample was previously working with qiskit 0.16.2 when `Statevector_simulator` was used for `AmplitudeEstimation`. Though I used to run  into an error ERROR_RUNNING_JOB when running on `ibmq_` hardware. I was told to upgrade to `qiskit 0.18` to fix that.

Since the update it now fails in `_check_conflicting_argument` with  the message "`The parameters pass_manager conflicts with the following parameter(s): backend.`" as shown below is a stack trace

```
    :
qc = compiler.transpile(circuit, BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), pass_manager=p_m)

File "C:\Users\-----\Anaconda3\envs\qiskite\lib\site-packages\qiskit\compiler\transpile.py", line 188, in transpile
        routing_method=routing_method, backend=backend)

File "C:\Users\------\Anaconda3\envs\qiskite\lib\site-packages\qiskit\compiler\transpile.py", line 225, in _check_conflicting_argument
        "parameter(s): {}.".format(', '.join(conflicting_args)))

TranspilerError: 'The parameters pass_manager conflicts with the following parameter(s): backend.'
```

Further walk through the stack trace shows the following

```
bckend = set_backend('STATEVEC')

ampest = AmplitudeEstimation(m, fixed_income)
result = ampest.run(quantum_instance=bckend)
..quantum_algorithm.run()
....ae.run
......if _quantum_instance.is_statevector:
........construct_circuit(measurement = False)
..........pec = PhaseEstimationCircuit(...)
..........pec.construct_circuit(measurement = False)
............._state_n_circuit_factory(qc,q,aux)
................uncertainty_model.build(...) #fixed_income_....py
..................cs = Custom(...) #multivariate_distribution.py
..................extend(cs.construct_circuit('circuit',q))   
.....................cs.construct_circuit('circuit')
........................svc = StateVectorCircuit(_state_vector)
........................sv.construct_circuit(...)
..........................convert_to_basis_gates()
............................Unroller(...)
............................PassManager(...)
............................compiler.transpile(circuit, BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator)...)
.............................. transpile (....)
................................._check_conflicting_argument(...backend=backend)
```

It is in this `_check_conflicting_argument` that the error message is raised `"The parameters pass_manager conflicts with the following parameter(s): backend."` and the script stops execution.

Please let me know what am I missing something here.

Thank you

Comment: Concerning the gates after the measurements; this was a bug that was fixed recently, are you using the latest version of Aqua?

Comment: @jul - thank you - it was `qiskit 0.16.2` - I updated to `qiskit 0.18` - I updated the description above

Comment: Hi! If you want to transpile the circuit for a specific backend, that should be the one you use in the transpile function. If you want to run it on a simulator you can just call `execute`

Comment: @met927 - Thank you - that beats me! I understand what you are saying but cant fully understand the reason for the error. I am updating Q above.

Comment: @abhi I'm not certain this caused your error, just a thought :) perhaps if you could share more of the code that is causing the error we could debug further?

Comment: @Abhi Thanks for the info. This bug is resolved in the latest master version, which is not yet in stable. Installing from source should resolve the issue, see my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer to your problem is to install Qiskit Aqua directly from GitHub instead of via pip. On the lastest master version, this bug is fixed. You can do this using

```
git clone https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua
cd qiskit-aqua
pip install .
```

more detailed instructions are given on [Qiskit's webpage](https://qiskit.org/documentation/contributing_to_qiskit.html#installing-aqua-from-source).

As to why you're getting this error: This comes from a change in Qiskit Terra which resulted in an incompatibility with the current implementation in Qiskit Aqua. That was fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/commit/ecf62693ea82ae360beb2d017fdffe220f740f14) on GitHub. This fix is in the master branch of the repository, however when you're installing via pip you're getting the last stable version, where this fix is not yet included. With the next release of Aqua (this will be 0.7.0) this bug is resolved in the pip version, too.